# unable to add helm addon to minishift on mac

Tags: macos, docker, minishift, kubernetes-helm

Installed minikube and try adding helm addon
always fails with message
-- Applying addon 'helm':..Error applying the add-on: Error executing  command 'ssh command error:
command : docker run --rm -v /home/docker:/root:z -v   /var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.config:/var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.config:z --net=host --env   KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig --env HELM_HOST=localhost:8443 lachlanevenson/k8s-helm:v2.8.1 init
err     : exit status 1
output  : Creating /root/.helm
Creating /root/.helm/repository
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local
Creating /root/.helm/plugins
Creating /root/.helm/starters
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Error: error installing: Post   http://localhost:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
':

minishift status indicates openshift is not running

minishift status
Minishift:  Running
Profile:    minishift
OpenShift:  Stopped
DiskUsage:  ERR of  (Mounted On: )
CacheUsage: 1.638 GB (used by oc binary, ISO or cached images)

I am stuck here. appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

The issue seams in http://localhost:8080 while HELM_HOST=localhost:8443 should set https instead of plain http.

Comment: It's a openshift v.3.10 specific issue, it still works with openshift 3.9.10.
I opened https://github.com/minishift/minishift-addons/issues/161